# openui5: How to implement animation only for the first render of custom component

Tags: sapui5

I'm implementing some custom components for openui5/sapui5.

For the component, I want to have a css animation when it is initially loaded.
This is quite straight forward as I add the following css:

```
@-webkit-keyframes card-in-animation {
   from {
     -webkit-transform: translateY(50em) rotate(5deg);
     opacity:0;
   }
}

.card {
   animation:card-in-animation  0.7s .2s ease-out both;
   -webkit-animation:card-in-animation  0.7s .2s ease-out both;
}
```

The problem arises when the component is re-rendered for some reason by the openui5 framework.

The DOM elements are then destroyed and new ones are created.
This causes the animation to triggered once again.

To see this in practice:

1. Go to http://elsewhat.github.io/openui5-cards/cdn/latest/example3.html
2. The initial animation is triggered as wanted
3. Click on the menu icon in the top right corner of any card
4. A new unwanted animation is triggered

What's the preferred method of avoiding this in openui5?

Comment: the openui5-cards development is looking good, you see any similarities to creating Android views?

Comment: Thanks @Jasper_07 . Not quite sure what you are asking for. The implementation is very different from Android code and I actually in many ways prefer the HTML+CSS approach. And with the powerful binding of openui5, the components are very easily reused in other projects

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside of your renderer you can set an flag that this control/component is rendered once.
second time you'll run into this renderer you'll check this flag and doesn't render this specific class.

```
if(!oControl._renderedOnce)  {
  oRm.addClass('rotate');
  oControl._renderedOnce = true;
}

oRm.writeClasses();
```

Comment: Thanks, added a internal property for this purpose and it works well. Full code in the github commit https://github.com/elsewhat/openui5-cards/commit/cba93303dcbca4df95d5dcca8379ebb9e20191f2

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how to overcome the unwanted re-rendering, but would it be an option to remove the animation class after the cards are rendered? (You may need to trigger it after a few seconds after onLoad for all cards to be set in place)

Something like this:

```
$("<element_of_your_cards>").removeClass("card")
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what you would normally do with css. However, rerendering (which happens sometimes) in openui5 will remove all the HTML elements from the DOM and re-add them. Therefore, you get the class added back again. There is an animation-end listener you could use, but it won't work if the elements have been removed. I probably need to keep track of it's the first rendering in the actual control